# How do I reference a TextBox that was created at runtime?

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I am creating an app where I need to run multiple instances of a timer. I defined labels, buttons, textboxes etc, but when I'm running the code, I get a NullReferenceException saying there is no instance of the object. I need to get data in a textbox defined in another method of same class. 
Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace week2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public int i=0;
        public int input;
        public int temp;
        public int hrs;
        public int min;
        public int sec;


        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {




            Label label1 = new Label();
            int count = panel1.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList().Count;
            label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(255, 20+(160*i));
            label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(103, 13);
            label1.Name = "label_" + (count + 1);
            label1.Text = "Time (Seconds) :";
            panel1.Controls.Add(label1);

            Label label2 = new Label();
            count = panel1.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList().Count;
            label2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(33, 20+(160* i));
            label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(150, 20);
            label2.Name = "label_" + (count + 1);
            label2.Text = "Timer " + (i + 1);
            panel1.Controls.Add(label2);

            Button button2 = new Button();
            count = panel1.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList().Count;
            button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(283, 72+(160*i));
            button2.Text = "Start";
            button2.Name = "Start";
            button2.Size= new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
            panel1.Controls.Add(button2);

            Button button3 = new Button();
            count = panel1.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList().Count;
            button3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(283, 101 + (160 * i));
            button3.Text = "Pause";
            button3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            button3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            button3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button3_Click);
            panel1.Controls.Add(button3);

            Button button4 = new Button();
            count = panel1.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList().Count;
            button4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(283, 130 + (160 * i));
            button4.Text = "Delete";
            button4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            button4.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            button4.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button4_Click);
            panel1.Controls.Add(button4);

            TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox();
            count = panel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList().Count;
            textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(283, 46+(160*i));
            textBox1.Text = null;
            textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
            textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 20);
            textBox1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_Changed);
            panel1.Controls.Add(textBox1);


            Timer timer1 = new Timer();
            timer1.Interval = 1000;
            timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);

            Label label3 = new Label();
            count = panel1.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList().Count;
            label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(40, 72 + (160 * i));
            label3.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 20.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            label3.Name = "hour";
            label3.Text = "00";
            label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(44, 31);
            panel1.Controls.Add(label3);

            Label label4 = new Label();
            count = panel1.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList().Count;
            label4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(90, 72 + (160 * i));
            label4.Text = ":";
            label4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(23, 31);
            label4.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 20.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            panel1.Controls.Add(label4);

            Label label5 = new Label();
            count = panel1.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList().Count;
            label5.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(119, 72 + (160 * i));
            label5.Text = "00";
            label5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(46, 31);
            label5.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 20.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            label5.Name = "minute";
            panel1.Controls.Add(label5);



            Label label6 = new Label();
            count = panel1.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList().Count;
            label6.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(171, 72 + (160 * i));
            label6.Text = ":";
            label6.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 20.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            label6.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(23, 31);
            panel1.Controls.Add(label6);


            Label label7 = new Label();
            count = panel1.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList().Count;
            label7.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(200, 72 + (160 * i));
            label7.Text = "00";
            label7.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(46, 31);
            label7.Name = "second";
            label7.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 20.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            panel1.Controls.Add(label7);


            Panel panel2 = new Panel();
            panel2.SuspendLayout();
            panel2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 15 + (160 * i));
            count = panel1.Controls.OfType<Panel>().ToList().Count;
            panel2.Name = "panel2";
            panel2.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            panel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(440, 150);
            panel1.Controls.Add(panel2);

            i = i + 1;
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button Start = (sender as Button);
            TextBox textBox1 = (sender as TextBox);
            Timer timer1 = (sender as Timer);
            Button Pause = (sender as Button);
            Label hour = (sender as Label);
            Label minute = (sender as Label);
            Label second = (sender as Label);

            if (Pause.Text == "Pause")
            {
                Pause.Text = "Resume";
                timer1.Enabled = false;

                Pause.Enabled = true;
                Start.Enabled = true;
            }
            else if (Pause.Text == "Resume")
            {
                Pause.Text = "Pause";
                timer1.Enabled = true;

                Pause.Enabled = true;
                Start.Enabled = true;
            }
        }


        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button Start = (sender as Button);
            TextBox textBox1 = (sender as TextBox);
            Timer timer1 = (sender as Timer);
            Button Pause = (sender as Button);
            Label hour = (sender as Label);
            Label minute = (sender as Label);
            Label second = (sender as Label);

            if ((hrs == 0) && (min == 0) && (sec == 0))
            {
                timer1.Enabled = false;
                MessageBox.Show("Time Out");

                Start.Text = "Start";
                Pause.Text = "Pause";

                Pause.Enabled = true;
                Start.Enabled = true;

                textBox1.Clear();
                textBox1.Enabled = true;

                hour.Text = "00";
                minute.Text = "00";
                second.Text = "00";

            }
            else
            {
                if (sec < 1)
                {
                    sec = 59;
                    if (min == 0)
                    {
                        min = 59;
                        if (hrs != 0)
                        {
                            hrs -= 1;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        min -= 1;
                }
                else
                    sec -= 1;
                hour.Text = hrs.ToString("D2");
                minute.Text = min.ToString("D2");
                second.Text = sec.ToString("D2");
            }
        }

        public void textBox1_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox textBox1 = (sender as TextBox);
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button Delete = (sender as Button);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Web.UI.Control myControl1 = new System.Web.UI.Control();
            myControl1 = myControl1.FindControl("textBox1");
            Button Start = (sender as Button);
            TextBox textBox1 = (myControl1 as TextBox);
            Timer timer1 = (sender as Timer);
            Button Pause = (sender as Button);
            Label hour = (sender as Label);
            Label minute = (sender as Label);
            Label second = (sender as Label);

            if (Start.Text == "Start")
            {

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Input");
                }
                else
                {

                    input = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

                    if ((input >= 0))
                    {
                        Start.Text = "Restart";
                        timer1.Enabled = true;
                        textBox1.Enabled = false;

                        Pause.Enabled = true;

                        try
                        {
                            temp = input / 60;
                            if (temp < 60)
                            {
                                hrs = 0;
                                min = temp;
                                sec = input % 60;
                            }
                            else if (temp >= 60)
                            {
                                hrs = temp / 60;
                                min = temp % 60;
                                sec = input % 60;

                            }
                            hour.Text = hrs.ToString("D2");
                            minute.Text = min.ToString("D2");
                            second.Text = sec.ToString("D2");
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Wrong input");
                        textBox1.Text = "";
                    }

                }

            }

            else if (Start.Text == "Restart")
            {
                Start.Text = "Start";

                timer1.Enabled = false;

                Pause.Enabled = false;
                Pause.Text = "Pause";

                textBox1.Clear();
                textBox1.Enabled = true;

                hour.Text = "00";
                minute.Text = "00";
                second.Text = "00";

            }
        }

    }
}
```

What is causing this error, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: This has been wrongly marked as duplicate where the link has relationship with the question

Comment: using System.Windows.Forms; namespace shouldn't be included on an ASP.NET application it has no reason to exists on the app

Comment: this is not an asp .net application. it is a windows forms application :(

Comment: tag said asp.net that where the confusion lies

Comment: yes.. the tag was added automatically and i didnt review the tag. however, any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `FindControl` instead

```
private void button2_click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// Find control on page.
      Control myControl1 = FindControl("textBox1");
      if(myControl1 != null)
      {
         // Get control's parent.
        TextBox textBox1 = (myControl1 as TextBox);
        if (textBox1 != null && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
        {
          /*code*/;
        }
         Response.Write("Parent of the text box is : " + myControl1.ID);
      }
      else
      {
         Response.Write("Control not found");
      }
//...
```

Comment: You don't _have_ to, but it's probably the most straight-forward way to handle the issue.

Comment: Control is under System.Web.UI while TextBox is under System.Windows.Forms . Conversion error. what to do?

Comment: @AtchyutSreekar no way both are under Web.UI windows forms controls cannot be used within an ASP.NET application

Comment: I'm editing the question and posting the entire code. look at it.

Comment: it is not an asp .net application.. it is a windows forms application

Answer (score 1):

It's not at all obvious what you're trying to do. But the null reference exception there is because the sender is NOT a textbox

You probably want to reference the textbox directly instead